# Problem: ArrayList size increasing

Tags: java, android-emulator, arraylist

hi am working with parsing xml file,i am returning `ArrayList` of class `Objects`, but **for every call of this method, the size of the ArrayList is increasing from 0-8 and 8 to 16 and 24... instead of creating a new ArrayList object**.

Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<clsCategory> ParseCategoryXml(String fileToParse)
{
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("before XML Pasing Array size is = " + categoryArray.size());

            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            //URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://d.mobrobot.com/feeds/npv1/categories_Fox.xml");
            FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(fileToParse);
            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            xr.setContentHandler(this);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(inputFile));
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Array size is = " + categoryArray.size());
    return categoryArray;
}
```

**Output in the Console for**

```
XML Pasing Array size is = 8  //when First call of method
XML Pasing Array size is = 16  //when Secondcall of method
```

Can anyone explain me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `categoryArray` is not local variable, it is an instance variable.. That is why its size increases for every call..

Comment: thx,my problem solved bit the problem is ArrayList() is instance variable

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you are creating a new ArrayList anywhere in your code, so each time you run the parsing code, the parsed elements are appended to the old one.

Try something like:

```
categoryArray = new ArrayList<clsCategory>();
```

at the start of the method.

Comment: no i am calling 'new ArrayList<clsCategory>();'<br>
 in out side the method